# Connecting to TFS in the cloud, getting windows authentication without popup using powershell

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, tfs

I am using this module `Az.Accounts` but this will popup a message to the user and I want to avoid this popup by getting the Windows credentials from the current session as the module VSTeam does (`Set-VSTeamAccount -Account "https://tfs..." -UseWindowsAuthentication`)

```
[PSCredential]$creds = Get-Credential
$null = Connect-AzAccount -Credential $creds
$accessToken = (Get-AzAccessToken -ErrorAction Stop).Token
$header = @{
            'Authorization' = 'Basic ' + [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($accessToken)"))
            }
Set-VSTeamAccount -Account https://dev.azure.com/Organization -PersonalAccessToken $accessToken
```

Comment: Most systems like Azure are moving from Windows Authentication to token based OAUTH2 because OAUTH2 is supported on Window, Linux, and MAC.

Comment: My question was how to get the Windows cred without the popup

Comment: There is more than one type of authentication.  You have to use the type the server is using.  If you are using the correct authentication than the pop up should go away.  Windows authentication is automatically performed with your code and if the server accepts windows authentication you should not get a popup.  Which probably means the server isn't using Windows Authentication.